# AWS workspacesclient not getting installed properly in Ubuntu 22.04 and not getting connected to AWS Client Desktop

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-22.04

**I am not able to install AWS workspacesclient in Ubuntu 22.04 and also I am not able to connect to AWS Client Desktop.**

I am getting the below error,

```
nxxxx@CT00569:/etc/apt$ sudo apt-get install workspacesclient
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 workspacesclient : Depends: libhiredis0.13 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**libhiredis0.13 in ubuntu 22.04,**

```
nxxx@CT00569:/etc/apt$ sudo apt-get install libhiredis0.13
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package libhiredis0.13 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libhiredis0.13' has no installation candidate
```

**I have tried installing workspacesclient in Ubuntu 22.04 using aptitude got the below error**

```
nXXX@CT00569:/etc/apt$ sudo aptitude install workspacesclient
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  workspacesclient{b} 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
Need to get 26.8 MB of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 workspacesclient : Depends: libhiredis0.13 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     workspacesclient [Not Installed]          



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

**I have tried all the steps mentioned**

```
@CT00569:/etc/apt$ sudo aptitude install libssl-dev
[sudo] password for nXXXX: 
libssl-dev is already installed at the requested version (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.6)
libssl-dev is already installed at the requested version (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.6)
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

**I have followed all the steps for installing aws workspacesclient**
`https://clients.amazonworkspaces.com/linux-install`

[AWS workspaceclient connection error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APzkg.png)

Comment: Would you mind to try what apt suggests you need to do manually, which is installing [libhiredis0.13](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libhiredis0.13)? Note that `workspacesclient` seems to be deprecated and you will likely face [other errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406567/amazon-workspaces-client-not-working-on-22-04)

Answer (score 0):

**I have resolved the issue by adding the ubuntu package repository with the required keys**

```
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe to /etc/apt/sources.list 

@CT00569:/etc/apt$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.3ulBZbLjWB/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
gpg: key 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32: public key "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1

nxxx@CT00569:/etc/apt$ sudo apt-get install libhiredis0.13
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libhiredis0.13
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
Need to get 25.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 73.7 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 libhiredis0.13 amd64 0.13.3-2.2 [25.3 kB]
Fetched 25.3 kB in 1s (21.6 kB/s)         
Selecting previously unselected package libhiredis0.13:amd64.
(Reading database ... 223483 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libhiredis0.13_0.13.3-2.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libhiredis0.13:amd64 (0.13.3-2.2) ...
Setting up libhiredis0.13:amd64 (0.13.3-2.2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
nxxx@CT00569:/etc/apt$ sudo apt-get install workspacesclient
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  workspacesclient
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
Need to get 26.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://d3nt0h4h6pmmc4.cloudfront.net/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 workspacesclient amd64 4.3.0.1766 [26.8 MB]
Fetched 26.8 MB in 7s (3,911 kB/s)                                                                                                    
Selecting previously unselected package workspacesclient.
(Reading database ... 223487 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../workspacesclient_4.3.0.1766_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking workspacesclient (4.3.0.1766) ...
Setting up workspacesclient (4.3.0.1766) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
nxxx@CT00569:/etc/apt$
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue as you, and trying Nick's solution didn't work.

However, I went to: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/hiredis/

and downloaded libhiredis0.13_0.13.3-2_amd64.deb (my architecture) and installed using:

```
sudo dpkg -i libhiredis0.13_0.13.3-2_amd64.deb
```

And then, I was able to install AWS Workspace and use it.

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Download the amazon workspaces client ".deb" file

```
wget https://d3nt0h4h6pmmc4.cloudfront.net/workspacesclient_focal_amd64.deb
```

Install the deb file

```
sudo dpgk --install workspacesclient_focal_amd64.deb
```

Force dependencies resolve

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```